# How to create a Seam project for Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, jsf, intellij-idea, seam

Can somebody tell me how can I create an Seam project for Intellij IDEA? I tried with Maven, but I do not have any success running it after and the plugin for Seam project in IDEA is rather old. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Seam project from Maven and then open the project from IDEA. If you have a Seam framework support right click on the project's root and 'Add framework support...'